# Maven : Changing the versions of the jars inside the dependency Tag

Tags: maven-2

We are using Maven 2.2.1 version .

I have an existing POM.xml file , in that i have observed a lot of jars 
were mentioned with the version 99.1 , look this below :

```
<dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-jaxws_2.1_spec</artifactId>
                <version>99.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec</artifactId>
                <version>99.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
```

Later i have chnaged the versions from 99.1 to exact version (For example in case of
geronimo-jaxws_2.1_spec jar i mentioned version as 1.7.1 )

Now this looks like this

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-jaxws_2.1_spec</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
```

The application got compiled , and its BUILD SUCCESSFUL .

But i dont know , chnaging like this will impact anything ??

And also i observed that for some of the jars on to dependency tag there is no version tag ?? Is this  acceptable ??

Please tell me , Thank you  very much .

Comment: Was it compiling before you updated the versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everything works and you know that 1.7.1 is correct version than you have no problem. Unfortunately there are all kind of version naming schemes that make it hard sometimes to figure what is what. So it's not clear what version 99.1 corresponds to. I seen this kind of situations with other products as well.

> And also i observed that for some of the jars on to dependency tag there is no version tag > ?? Is this acceptable ??

Versions are probably defined in the parent pom in `dependencyManagement` section. In this case children poms will not need explicit version specified.

Comment: Thank you very much , could you please tell me what do you mean by  "there are all kind of version naming schemes that make it hard sometimes to figure what is what." ??

Comment: I have seen cases when official version 1.0 of some product was distributed with timestamp as a version. It was very painful as there was no way to tell which specific version is inside jar. So your switch to proper version is a good move.